# ASP.NET MVC passing parameter to @RenderPage("", new{Test = Test} ) gives error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I got a dashboard page which includes 4 partial view.

I just need to give data as parameter to partial view from inside the  `Index.cshtml`.

Here's my `Index.cshtml` code (top of the page):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
}

@using CoreLibrary.Extensions
@using System.Data
@{
    Business.ReportBll.DailyParams prms = new Business.ReportBll.DailyParams();
    prms.end = DateTime.Now; 
    prms.start = DateTime.Now.FirstDayOfMonth();  
    var DataDaily= Business.Report.ReportDaily(prms, true);            
    HtmlString baslangicBitisTarSpan = new HtmlString((prms.strdate.HasValue ? "<span style='margin-left:5px'>Başlangıç:"
            + prms.strdate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
            + "</span>" : ""));
}
```

Middle of the `Index.cshtml`, giving parameter to oage

```
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Report/_DashDaily.cshtml",   new { DataDaily = DataDaily })
     
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
            @RenderPage("~/Views/Report/_DashboardWeek.cshtml")// data will be added here soon
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside the _DashDaily.cshtml top of

```
@using CoreLibrary.Extensions
@using System.Data

@{       
    var k1 = DataDaily;
    var k = @DataDaily;
}
```

Finally the Error is

> CS0103: The name 'DataDaily' does not exist in the current context

Its really simple but idk why i couldnt. Will you help me. Thanks

The type of return data

[image]

Comment: `DataDaily` is model class?

Comment: No its not a model class. It just returns data from giving sql

Comment: It's `DataSet` or `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

inside the _DashDaily.cshtml top of

```
@using CoreLibrary.Extensions
@using System.Data
@model DataTable//<YOUR Model Class>
@{
   
    var k1 = Model;    
}
```

Comment: DataDaily  which i give as paramater is not a model class. It just sql returned data

Comment: Agreed but it's must be `DataSet` or `DataTable`.

Comment: Added photo at the bottom

Comment: Okay then go with `DataTable` check the answer I've modified the code.

Comment: Nope it still gives error

Comment: I added my answer.Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this.

```
@using CoreLibrary.Extensions
@using System.Data 
@{
   
   var DataDaily = @Page.DataDaily;
}
```